# Formatting Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, worksheet-function

I have the following formula:

```
 =D56&" "&"("&D57&" Days"&")"
```

`D56` has a date within the cell.  I want to format the date like `5/5/2011` but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=TEXT(D56,"mm/dd/yyyy") & " " & "(" & D57 & " Days" & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click cell, choose format cells, choose number tab -> date and then choose the appropriate date format to the right.